# Is there any problem if the last name prints first than the first name on an air ticket?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

Is there any problem if the last name prints first then the first name in international air ticket?

Comment: ticket? boarding pass? emailed itinerary? What are you seeing and what did you expect to see or usually see?

Comment: I wrote them in reverse (first name in last name form and vice-versa) on a Ryanair ticket and boarded regularly. Maybe it just passed unnoticed, since everything was written correctly =)

Comment: Rahul, it will not be a problem.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean "Ms Jane Doe" getting reversed into "DOE/JANEMS" like the boarding pass below, that's completely normal:

[image]

(courtesy [Heb on Wikimedia Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Boarding_card_-_text_as_paths.svg))

Answer (score 3):

As a Brit I use my married name, but on the Continent they address me by my maiden name or both names. So I got a passport with both names. My credit card has both names, but in a different order! So I often end up with tickets that have my names in a different order to my passport. This is never an issue, as I think airlines and security have to be aware that conventions vary so same names, different order has to be accepted.