# Name in passport as BCA in place of ABC; cause for visa refusal?

Tags: schengen, passports, paperwork, visa-refusals

My name in my passport is written in the wrong order, i.e. in place of ABC it is written as BCA. Can this be a reason for rejection of a visa to Germany? If yes, is there any solution? What steps could I take to demonstrate that both names belong to one person?

Comment: Why don´t you get a correct passport, to avoid all possible problems?

Comment: _Can this be a reason for rejection of a visa to Germany?_ **Yes** - _is there any solution?_ **Get a new passport!**

Comment: Was there no reason given for the visa refusal?

Comment: Is this an *error* or do you come from a country where names are traditionally written in a different order from Germany?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any problem if the last name prints first than the first name in international air ticket?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24725/is-there-any-problem-if-the-last-name-prints-first-than-the-first-name-in-intern)

Comment: I think the most important question is if your passport is correct for the country from which it was issued? Are all passports written in that order? If so, your fine. If not, fix it by getting a new passport.

Comment: Is this an error, or an issue where your country places name components in a different order? In the former case, I think you need a new or officially-corrected passport. In the latter, I would think which is your family name (last name, in Germany) will be labeled.

Answer (score 1):

Having a passport list your name as BCA potentially makes it invalid, since it doesn't reflect your true identity. Same would apply if the passport had a different birthdate or a different name altogether. While having such a passport is not fraudulent, it's a potential reason for visa refusal at the embassy.

I would suggest applying for a new passport to rectify the problem and avoid issues with migration in the future.