# Firstname and Lastname confusion while ticket booking

Tags: visas, tickets, passports

My father is having an Indian passport and it has the name as following

**Given name** = XXX YYY

**Surname** = Blank

When I applied for US tourist visa, they gave him the same but in that his name is shown like

**First Name** = FNU

**Last Name** = XXX YYY

**Now I am confused that while booking a flight what should I use for First and Last names?** I should go with the Passport or with VISA?

Comment: You should use his name, "XXX YYY".

Comment: yes, I should use 'XXX YYY', but As a First name or Last name?

Comment: Usually for people who have only a single name, the airlines just have you repeat it in both fields, or place the name in one field and a literal `XXX` in the other field. If he doesn't have a single name, and the passport has both names in the given name field, then you should book the tickets normally (and get the passport fixed).

Comment: Repetition is not allowed, I am waiting for answer who have faced similar issue.

Comment: Your waiting is over!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any problem if the last name prints first than the first name in international air ticket?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24725/is-there-any-problem-if-the-last-name-prints-first-than-the-first-name-in-intern)

Comment: I don't this is a duplicate. The other question was about how the name was printed on the ticket, this question is about buying a ticket in the first place.

Comment: Isn't this how/why we get questions about people who's tickets show a first name of Mr. ?

Comment: Facing the exact same issue, what worked for you @Dhiman ??

Comment: I used what was mentioned in Passport, so used XXX YYY in First Name and used ‘LNU’ in last name (last name unknown).

Answer (score 3):

My first thought is to go with whatever works. If the ticket system allows for no last, or surname, then follow the passport, since that is your travel ID. If it requires a surname, but allows for no given name, do that. If it requires both a surname and a given name, put Mr. as the given (first) name, and your father's name as the surname.

My guess is, the system will require both a last name and a first name, so XXX YYY and Mr.

If you read through other questions here, you'll find this appears to be fairly common with certain countries. As long as his name, XXX YYY appears in the passport, the visa, and the ticket, it's very unlikely that he'll have problems at all.